# Custom Widget Not Saving Values to Database

Tags: php, wordpress

**UPDATE:** Looks like they are getting saved but the current values arent being displayed in the drop down boxes when the form is reloaded in admin (after saving). I have the lines for "selected" but I'm not sure what I'm missing in order to get them to show the current values.

I'm trying to create a widget that will allow you to pick a CTA and a Landing Page from two separate drop down menus. The drop downs are populated based on two custom post types which is working fine. My problem is that I can't figure out how to save the values to teh database (i.e., clicking save on the widget in the admin doesn't commit the values to the database.

Here are the relevant functions from my widget class called cta_widget. (I left out the code for the 2nd dropdown as it's identical).

```
<?php
function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
{
    $instance = $old_instance;

    /* Strip tags (if needed) and update the widget settings. */
    $instance['cta_id'] = $new_instance['cta_id'];
    $instance['url_id'] = $new_instance['url_id'];

    return $instance;
}

function form($instance) {
    /* Set up some default widget settings. */
    $defaults = array('cta_id' => '23', 'url_id' => '28');
    $instance = wp_parse_args((array)$instance, $defaults);
?>
<p> 
    <label
        for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('cta_id'); ?>"><?php _e('CTA:'); ?></label>

    <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('cta_id'); ?>"
            id="cta_id<?php echo $this->get_field_name('cta_id'); ?>"
            style="width:100%;">
        <option value=""></option>

        <?php

        $posts = get_posts(
            array(
                'post_type'   => 'locable_ctas',
                'numberposts' => -1
            )
        );
        if ($posts) {

            foreach ($posts as $p) {
                if ($p == $selected) {
                    $selected = "selected = 'selected'";
                } else {
                    $selected = "";
                }
                echo '<option value="' . $p->ID . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $p->post_title . '</option>';
            }
        }

        ?>
    </select>
</p>
}
```

Comment: Figure it out. Here is the correct code:

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is the code for anyone else having the same issue.

```
function form( $instance ) { 

        $cta = $instance['cta_id']; 
        $lp = $instance['lp_id'];       

        /* Set up some default widget settings. */  
        $defaults = array( 'cta_id' => '', 'lp_id' => '');  
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults );   

        ?>

        <p>  

        <?php echo 'CTA: '.$cta;?>
        <?php echo 'LP: '.$lp.'<br/>';?>

        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'cta_id' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'CTA:' ); ?></label> 

            <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'cta_id' ); ?>" id="cta_id<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'cta_id' ); ?>" style="width:100%;">
            <option value=""></option>

            <?php

            $posts = get_posts(
                array(
                    'post_type'  => 'locable_ctas',
                    'numberposts' => -1
                )
            );
            if($posts)
            {

                foreach( $posts as $p )
                {
                    if ($p->ID==$cta)
                    {
                        $is_selected = "selected = 'selected'";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $is_selected = "";
                    }
                    echo '<option value="' . $p->ID . '" '.$is_selected.'>' .$p->post_title  . '</option>';
                }
            } 

        ?>
        </select>

        </p>

        <p>  

        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'lp_id' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'LP:' ); ?></label> 

            <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'lp_id' ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'lp_id' ); ?> style="width:100%;"">
            <option value=""></option>

            <?php

            $posts = get_posts(
                array(
                    'post_type'  => 'locable_lps',
                    'numberposts' => -1
                )
            );
            if($posts)
            {
                foreach( $posts as $p )
                {
                    if ($p->ID==$lp)
                    {
                        $is_selected = "selected = 'selected'";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $is_selected = "";
                    }
                    echo '<option value="' . $p->ID . '" '.$is_selected.'>' .$p->post_title  . '</option>';
                }
            } 

        ?>
        </select>

        </p>            

        <?php  
    }
```